# Doc-view not working despite gs being in my path

Tags: pdf, docview

I have trouble getting the `doc-view-mode` displaying pdfs. Here's the error message generated :

```
No PNG support is available, or some conversion utility for pdf files is missing.
```

From what [I've gathered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26476882/152244), I must make sure that `gs` is in emacs path variable. Again, all of this looks good, the path given by

```
$which gs
```

is also found in `(getenv "PATH")`.

So I'm not too sure where the bug comes from, any idea?

Running OS X 10.10.3, Emacs 24.4, ghostscript 9.15

Comment: It should work out of the box if you have Ghostscript properly installed.  Try  setting the absolute path to the Ghostscript executable by adding to your `.emacs` file the following code `(setq doc-view-ghostscript-program "/path/to/gs")`  Then, restart Emacs and try opening a `*.pdf` file and see if you get the same error.  If it works, then you know the problem is not a missing something or other.

Comment: Working, Thanks ! Perhaps you could put your comment in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: So it's really the "PATH" variable that's responsible for it? Because as I said, both my $PATH (of the system) and the "PATH" of emacs include the directory where gs is found (`usr/local/bin`)